# browserify cannot find module when browser field specified in package.json

Tags: node.js, npm, browserify

As I understand it you use the browser field in package.json to specify your browser entry point like so:

```
"main": "index.js",
"browser": "browser.js",
```

I generate browser.js using browserify like so:

```
./node_modules/.bin/browserify index.js -o browser.js
```

And this works before I add the `"browser"` entry in `package.json`

However, after I add the `"browser"` entry the browserify command fails with:

> Cannot find module browser.js

Can anyone shed any light on this? Is my thinking conceptually wrong?

Comment: I'm having the same problem, maybe we're both missing something obvious